# Probability: find the probability of event B given that event A occurs

Tags: probability

My Problem,
Suppose a family has 2 children,
if one children is randomly selected and it is a girl then what is the probability of the second child to be a girl ?
Please help. Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is still $1/2$, since the fact that the randomly selected first child is a girl has no effect on the sex of the second child. There may be some subtle way that this question can be worded to change that, though.

Comment: @mapierce271 I think the answer is $1/2$ but the intuition behind jh4's answer is a bit off. I think it's worthy to note that the fact that you randomly selected a girl makes it *more* likely that both children are girls, since the possibility of both children being boys is eliminated.

Comment: If all you're told is that the family has at least one girl, then the answer is different.

Comment: @aes Then the answer is $1/3$ because there are three cases (all equally likely) in which the family has at least one girl, and only one of them is the case with two girls.

Comment: @mapierce271 Are we talking about aes's other problem, or OP's problem?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee sorry, thought you were talking about OP's problem.

Comment: @mapierce271 no worries :)

Comment: @mapierce271 : You are entirely ignoring the statement that one of the two is chosen at random.  It doesn't have to be the one born first.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That is just a poor word choice on my part. I didn't mean to imply that the choosen child was the first-born. Although it is arbitrary ("WLOG let the chosen child be the first-born child...").

Comment: @mapierce271 : In that case, several of the answers posted below and several of the comments posted above are wrong.  The probability is $1/3$, not $1/2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think I see what you are saying now. The question is a bit ambiguous. When OP said "the second child" I took that to mean "the child that was not chosen", but it could also mean "the second-born child." That matters quite a bit. OP should clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event that the you randomly selected a girl.

Let $B$ be the event that both children are girls.

Let $C$ be the event that one child is a boy and one is a girl.

---

$$P(A) = 1/2$$

$$P(B) = 1/4$$

$$P(C) = 1/2$$

---

What is $P(A \,\mid\,B)$? The probability that you randomly select a girl, given that both children are girls. This is clearly $1$.

---

We are looking for $P(B \,\mid\,A)$. We can use Bayes' rule:

$$P(B\,\mid\,A) = \frac{P(A\,\mid\,B)\cdot P(B)}{P(A)}$$

$$P(B\,\mid\,A) = \frac{1 \cdot \frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$P(B\,\mid\,A) = \boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: This "accepted" answer is wrong.  See my answer. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Let's work by definition of conditional probabilities:

Let A = first child is girl, and B = second child is girl.

$$P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(A \cap B) }{P(A)}= \frac{0.5 \times 0.5}{0.5}=0.5$$

Comment: "if one children is randomly selected and it is a girl then what is the probability of the second child to be a girl".  Since one is selected at random, it may be the one who was born first or the one born second.  The term "the second" child usually means the one born after the first.  But in that conflicts with saying one is selected at random.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't think it makes a difference which order in which they are born.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee : You miss the point completely!!  See my posted answer here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't see what point I missed. What exactly is "wrong" with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

"if one children is randomly selected and it is a girl then what is the probability of the second child to be a girl"

This is one of the worst cases of ambiguity in a question that I've seen in a while.  "second child" usually means the one born after the first child, but that seems to conflict with the statement that one of the two is randomly chosen.  I have to construe "the second child" to mean "the other child".
$$
\begin{array}{ccl}
\text{first born} & \text{second born} \\
\hline
\text{boy} & \text{boy} & \longleftarrow\text{This case is ruled out.} \\
\text{boy} & \text{girl} \\
\text{girl} & \text{boy} \\
\text{girl} & \text{girl}
\end{array}
$$
If one of two randomly chosen is a girl, then in one of the three cases not ruled out, the other one is a girl.  So $1/3$ is the bottom line.

Comment: The boy-boy case *is* ruled out, and I *did* account for that. But if you look at the three remaining possibilities, they are *not* equally likely. There are four words "girl" that appear among the three possibilities, and the girl you've picked is equally likely to be any of those. So the probability that both are girls is $2/4 = 1/2$.

Comment: The probability is only $1/3$ in the case that @aes discussed in the comment thread on the original question.

Comment: This is based on how I read the question. As you've already pointed out there's some ambiguity with "second child" but I don't think he meant "second child" in the sense of second-born.